# Signature verification in c# with bouncy castle api

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, sign

I'm attempting to make use of the Bouncy Castle apis to verify the signature of a clear signed message. (I've got signing, encryption, and decryption working, but some of the things I need to verify won't have been encrypted so I need to be able to do these separately).

I want to verify the signature, and if it is verified then return just the message text (without signature).
My function at the moment is the following;

```
public string GetVerifiedMessage(string signedCleartext, PgpPublicKey publicKey)
    {
        var inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(ReadAsStream(signedCleartext));
        var outStr = new MemoryStream();

        inputStream.CopyTo(outStr);
        outStr.Close();

        var objectFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(inputStream);
        var signatureList = (PgpSignatureList) objectFactory.NextPgpObject();
        var signature = signatureList[0];

        var literalData = (PgpLiteralData) objectFactory.NextPgpObject();
        var data = literalData.GetInputStream();

        signature.InitVerify(publicKey);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        int ch;
        while ((ch = data.ReadByte()) >= 0)
        {
            signature.Update((byte) ch);
            memoryStream.WriteByte((byte) ch);
        }

        if (!signature.Verify())
        {
            throw new Exception("Signature was not verified");
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
```

This is based off the examples in the bouncy castle codebase and elsewhere, although I have had to vary them to do this in memory rather than writing to files.

When running this, I get an error because the objectFactory does not contain any pgp objects. I have verified that third party tools can verify the signature on the example message I'm using.

I've tried a few variations - not copying to outStr gives an "Unknown object in stream 45" exception on trying to get the PgpObject, which is annoying as in it's current form it is useless.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?